# Oculus Quest: Recording Video within the Oculus Quest

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculusquest

I'm working on a VR application (in Unity) for the Quest that one of its features is to be able to record yourself from a camera. I have tried some assets like VR capture (by RockVR), but they only work on certain platforms such as Windows or macOS. I have also tried capturing frames and then converting them to a .gif or .mp4 file but that also requires a platform-specific library. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You are just trying to record a video of your play session?

Comment: In a way, yes, but not from the first-person perspective that Oculus provides.